# How to show number like badge on marker on google map in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using multiple markers on map, and on click it show info window.
but I have multiple data at same lat-long, due to which only one marker show on map and rest are hidden.
I want to show number of data on the same lat-long as badge.
Please help.

Comment: The way I did on Apple maps to create a subclass of the annotation containing all the information in an array inside the subclass and the annotation itself is rendered with a badge icon. I guess it should work on google maps marker as well. What I do not know if you want to allow the user to interact with the callout it will work with google api or not because according to my memories callout are rendered as pictures in google maps api so the user cannot change its content after it is shown.

Comment: You can use [this third party Google Maps utility library](https://github.com/DDRBoxman/google-maps-ios-utils). You can use the [CGClusterManager](https://github.com/DDRBoxman/google-maps-ios-utils/blob/master/Clustering/GClusterManager.h) to manager your markers,  you can put your marker with same location into the `item` property.